# How to consume Restfull service in Oracle MAF Application

Tags: oracle, web-services, rest, oracle-maf

I am new to Oracle MAF Application FrameWork

I have created a RestFull Service using JDeveloper IDEwhich can perform basic login(Method=POST) operation.

Now i would like to consume this Restful service in my MAF application.

Consuming Rest Service i have done the following steps:

right click on ViewController-> New->from Gallery->DataControl(Business Tier)->WebService Data Control

Step 2:
           Select Rest and entered the URI

Step 3:   Add resource path with Post Method name

Step 4:   add param user id, password

Now when i clicked next button it shows me error

**Please provide an XML Schema to describe the input structure.
 Path = /path0, Method =dffds**

please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the MAF MCS Utility sample. See, [MAF MCS Utility: Accessing Oracle MCS from MAF Made Simple.](https://blogs.oracle.com/mobile/entry/maf_mcs_utility_accessing_oracle)

Another approach is to use the declarative support in Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse (OEPE) . See this step-by-step tutorial, [Consuming Mobile Cloud Service APIs using Eclipse.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E65774_01/tutorials/tut_mcs_oepe/tut_mcs_oepe_1.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can watch the youtube videos about the Consuming Rest Services in oracle maf.

Or else follow the below steps

Create the REST Connection.
Go to Projects panel, right-click ViewController project and choose New > From Gallery.
In the New Gallery dialog, choose General > Connections > REST Connection.

In Url Endpoint enter valid url eg:https://maps.googleapis.com (For google API)

If you click Test Connection button

Then in Backing Bean use following code:

```
String uri="your URI";
RestServiceAdapter restServiceAdapter = Model.createRestServiceAdapter();
restServiceAdapter.clearRequestProperties();
restServiceAdapter.setConnectionName("RestConnection name");
restServiceAdapter.setRequestType(RestServiceAdapter.REQUEST_TYPE_POST);
restServiceAdapter.addRequestProperty("accept", "application/json");
restServiceAdapter.setRetryLimit(0);
restServiceAdapter.getResponseHeaders();
restServiceAdapter.setRequestURI(uri);
setJsonResponse(restServiceAdapter.send(""));
```

This link clearly explains the steps go through it.

http://waslleysouza.com.br/en/2014/12/restjson-in-maf/